# How to keep a list of variables given some of them may not exist?

Tags: stata, capture, stata-macros

I have 100 `dta` files. I have a list of variables that I need to `keep` and save temporary copies on the fly. Some variables may or may not exist in a certain `dta`.

I need Stata to keep all variables that exist in a `dta` and ignore those that do not exist.

The following code has wrong syntax, but it could serve as a good pseudo code to give one a general idea of what should be done:

```
forval j = 1/100 {
    use data`j'
    local myVarList =""

    foreach i of varlist  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7 var8  {
        capture sum `i'
        if _rc = 0 {
            `myVarList' = `myVarList'" "`i'
        }
    }

    keep `myVarList'
    save temporaryData`j'
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many issues with your code. Here's one way to do the inner loop.

```
/* one fake dataset */
set obs 5
gen var1 = 1
gen var2 = 2
gen var3 = "c"
gen z    = 35

ds

/* keep part */
local masterlist "var1 var2"
local keeplist = ""

foreach i of local masterlist  {
    capture confirm variable `i'
        if !_rc {
            local keeplist "`keeplist' `i'"
        }
}

keep `keeplist'
```

The key part is that you can't `foreach i of varlist phantomvar`, since Stata will check the existence and error out. Similarly, putting the local name in special quotes will evaluate it, but you're trying to redefine. You may find `set trace on` a useful feature in debugging.

This is somewhat better code:

```
unab allvars: _all
local masterlist "var1 var2 phantomvar"
local keeplist: list allvars & masterlist
keep `keeplist'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, it does not work if the `masterlist` was: `local masterlist "var1 someNonexistingVar var2"`. My `.dta` files do not necessarily have all variables.

Comment: Good catch. "Existence" should have been "variable". Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. That works!!! May i ask about the `"This is somewhat better code:"` part... Where do i use it?

Comment: Replace everything under the /*keep part*/ with it.

Comment: The third line finds the intersection of the masterlist variables and the variables in the current data set and stores them in a local macro named keeplist. You will still need to loop over the data sets and save the new files.

Comment: For the record, in terms of the original code: "didn't work" can mean anything from "does not do what I want" to "is illegal"; here it's the latter. The line `\`myVarList' = \`myVarList'" "\`i'` contains several mistakes, starting with the lack of an initial `local`.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov i like the `better solution`. it is awesome. but i am confused about `local keeplist: list allvars & masterlist`. This line seems to work even without this part: `: list allvars &`... Why do i need to `unab` and then to join `&` it with `masterlist`? Thank you~

Comment: I don't think it should work. I certainly does not with my toy example. Start another question with some actual code.

Comment: `local keeplist` is perfectly legal. It just blanks out any existing local macro with the name `keeplist`, which on occasion is what you want.