# Keep a list of variables when some variables don't exist

Tags: loops, stata, capture, stata-macros

For several countries, I have one dataset and I want to keep a list of variables (specified in a global `vlist`) for each of them. Some variables do not exist in some countries.

I want Stata to ignore the non-existence of these variables and execute the `keep` command for the rest of the variables. However, the problem is the additional `for` loop on the country-level, that I'm struggling to incorporate.

This question is similar to the one asked in these threads:

- [Stata. How to `keep` a list of variables given some of them may not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056016/stata-how-to-keep-a-list-of-variables-given-some-of-them-may-not-exist)
- [How do I confirm existence of all respective variables of a variable list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252962/how-do-i-confirm-existence-of-all-respective-variables-of-a-variable-list)

Ultimately, I want to end up with a dataset for each country that has only those variables specified in the `vlist` (minus the ones from the `vlist` that do not exist).

Here's the code, which is mostly taken from the thread above:

```
clear all
set obs 5

local vlist v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5

foreach v of local vlist { 
    generate `v' = runiform()
}

save country1.DTA, replace
save country2.DTA, replace
save country3.DTA, replace

global vlist_example v0 v1 v6          // v6 is not part of the dataset

foreach country in country1 country2 country3 {
   local keeplist = ""
      foreach i of global vlist_example {
          capture confirm variable `i'
              if !rc {
                  local "`keeplist' `i'"
          }
      }
keep `keeplist'     
save `country'beta2.DTA, replace 

}
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
rc not found
r(111);
```

I hope this sufficiently describes my problem, but please let me know if anything needs more explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you do not call each dataset to modify it accordingly.

The following should give you what you want:

```
clear all
set obs 5

local vlist v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5

foreach v of local vlist { 
    generate `v' = runiform()
}

save country1, replace
save country2, replace
save country3, replace

global vlist_example v0 v1 v6          // v6 is not part of the dataset

foreach country in country1 country2 country3 {
    use `country'.dta, clear
    local keeplist ""
    foreach i of global vlist_example {
        capture confirm variable `i'
        if !_rc {
            local keeplist "`keeplist' `i'"
        }
    }
    keep `keeplist'     
    save `country'beta2, replace 
}
```

Note that after `capture` you need to type `!_rc` and *not* `!rc`.

Comment: A loop over variable names really isn't needed. This technique is often extremely useful, but here it leads to an indirect solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's an exercise in finding the intersections of various lists of names.

```
local wanted v0 v1 v6    

foreach set in country1 country2 country3 { 
   use `set', clear 
   describe, varlist 
   local this `r(varlist)' 
   local exist : list wanted & this 
   keep `exist'
   * save command here 
}
```

Note that looping over names is absolutely not needed.

Comment: This solution may appear counter-intuitive at first but it is equivalent to the one above. The difference is that the inner loop is substituted with macro list manipulation. See [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals/pmacrolists.pdf) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the plus, but what is _counter-intuitive_ here, e.g. puzzling or backwards? The syntax may be novel to a reader, but it's an implementation of "I need to identify the variables that actually exist from a list of those wanted"

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax you propose. If anything, it is more clean. But i think beginners find it easier to think in terms of loops than macro list manipulations. I have seen this several times before.

Comment: I see. That could well be, depending on their previous programming experience. I often see people programming unnecessary loops over observations.